# Binaries are added to /bin without a reference, why?

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I am using a custom built NuGet package with a set of binaries from DevExpress. Whenever I build the project from Visual Studio, a lot of "extra" DevExpress binaries, that I have not added a reference too, is also added to the bin folder.

I have installed a DevExpress suite of some sort so it might be that some of the GAC'ed binaries are added, but why ? I do not wish to have these binaries cluttering my bin folder.

VS references:

[image]

Bin folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be that assemblies knows its dependencies. The Assembly Explorer show you which:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rolf's answer.

If the reference is set to "local" in the project, the dll's will be moved to the output folder (\bin)
[image]

In the project those refenrences will have a `<private>True</Private>` tag:

fx:

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, ...>
  <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net40-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private> <-- HERE
</Reference>
```